# Applying HTML formatting in email's body

Tags: html, css, email, formatting, html-email

I am still trying to figure out, why i cannot apply HTML formatting in the body of a custom email. I am sure i am missing something, or i need a new pair of eyes!

Here is the info added to the `<head>` of the web page

```
<head runat="server">
    <link href="~/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

`Mystyle.css` contains the following

```
span.orange
{
    color: #FF6D06;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

and here comes the body part...

```
Dim HtmlString as string = "<span class='orange'>This one should be painted</span>"
```

which is sent by using Net.Mail

```
Dim objMail As New Mail.MailMessage (blah, blah blah)
objMail.IsBodyHtml = True
```

**UPDATE:** First of all thank you for your comments. The email itself is not in any way referenced with the style sheet in any way. So what options do i have besides attaching the style sheet to the email?

Comment: I'm confused.  How does the HTML in the email body reference your stylesheet?

Comment: It's not clear to me where the web page itself comes in. Please clarify. Ideally, provide a short but complete program...

Comment: Hello! I added the regarding info in the update above. Thank you

Comment: There’s a good article on coding up HTML e-mails here: http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When I've done this, I've typically embedded the CSS in the body of the email:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
span.orange
{
    color: #FF6D06;
    ...
}
</style>
</head>
...
```

Avoid referencing external entities (like stylesheets, images, etc.) in HTML email.  Those references may not be available, depending on the user's mail agent settings.  Also, learn about the HTML support in mail agents.  It may not be as rich as you expect.  [Here's some information on Outlook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx), for instance.

Answer (score 7):

As noted by others, defining your styles inline is the best option. Here are a couple of articles that you might find useful:

[Rock Solid HTML Emails](http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails)

[Guide to CSS support in email clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: thenk you !, very helpful resources.

Answer (score 6):

It appears you are going about this incorrectly.

Your CSS should be inline, and not external.  Then you just have all of your HTML and CSS styles as the body of your email, and it will work.

You really want to avoid referencing outside files as many email applications will block the references.

Answer (score 0):

Most mail-readers *(both desktop-based and web-based)* don't deal great with CSS : it's generally better to not use and external CSS and use inline styles, it's often better to use tables for formating instead of divs, ...

And, here, where is your CSS ? Is it at least on a server somewhere ?

(i.e. it should not be only on your local machine, but accessible via some kind of URL)

Answer (score 0):

Color attribute won't work for e-mails, for most mail agents it might work the first time the e-mail is sent but it'll be ignored if the e-mail is forwarded.

Best thing is to use very old HTML tags and tables to format and style the e-mail, such as pre-tableless code.

Sad but true, support for e-mails is still incredibly poor.